# Implicit Wait & Multiple xpath elements

Tags: python, selenium

What I wanna do is to check if one of the 3 strings exists, so I want it to check for email address or email and if it does, it sends input, not sure how to do this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"email address")]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"email")]')
```

I'd want those to be in one line but not sure how.

````py
driver.implicitly_wait(1540)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"email address")]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="inputE"]').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id39"]/button').click()```
````

Comment: Can you share HTML code ?

Comment: Why won't `contains(text(), 'email')` work for both cases?

Comment: Its just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

This xpath `//[@id="inputE"]`, I have changed it to `id` :  `inputE` which looks quite static.

There isn't any requirement for `driver.implicitly_wait(1540)` with 1540 , instead try to give less time there.

You may opt for **Explicit wait** for this scenario, That said you should never mix **implicit** with **explicit**.

```
try:
 if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"email address")]').is_displayed():
   driver.find_element_by_id('inputE').send_keys("email_address")
except NoSuchElementException:
   print("Email address input field is not found")
```

Comment: I used explicit previously, just thought I'd test implicit, however it seems for checking if one of multiple elements exists, explicit is better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicit use explicit wait condition
Here is the example code:

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf("Element_path"));
```

After applying the explicit wait perform the operation you want to perform.

Comment: I do understand that, but how would I be able to check if one of the elements exists? say WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf("Element_path", "example_path"));

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverwait` and `presence_of_all_elements_located` and use the xpath.Then check the length count of the element if more than 0 it will go inside if block and execute remaining code.

```
if (len(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'email') or contains(.,'email address')]"))))>0):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputE"]').send_keys('email')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id39"]/button').click()
```

You need to add following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example xpath how you can handle the issue. Basically here we are checking if there is any span under div (change this based on your application hierarchy) with the specified text.

Just for understanding purpose, I added both the spans in the same html. I am sure the xpath will pick if either of them exist in the give path.

**Sample HTML:**

```html
<html>
  <div>
 <span>email</span>
 <input placeholder="email"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
 <span>email id</span>
 <input placeholder="email id"></input>
  </div>
  
  <div>
 <span>email address</span>
 <input placeholder="email address"></input>
  </div>
</html>
```

**Xpath:**

```
//div[contains("'email','email id'",span)]/input
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: FYI - you can just specify the text without single quotes, if there is no space in each `text()`. Eg: `//div[contains("1stSpan,2ndSpan,GoOnLikeThisIfNoSpaces")]`.

Comment: <span>email address </span> - //span[contains(text(), "'email address', 'email'")] and it isnt working, not sure why, its exactly same as yours.

Comment: what's the parent of the `<span>email address </span>`?

Comment: It doesnt have one

Comment: How come, the span does not have a parent? Can you please add the html screenshot of the span and ancestor.

Comment: Mate, its literally an test html site I made.

Comment: Is it possible to share your html if it does not have any sensitive information. I feel that missing something here.

Comment: It doesn't matter,  //*[contains(text(), "'email address', 'email'")]  doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. With the given screenshot html here are the possible options. Option 1: `//body//span[normalize-space(.)="email"]|//body//span[normalize-space(.)='email address']` Option 2: '//body//span[starts-with(normalize-space(.),"email")]`

Comment: I don't see the input and the button that you mentioned in the OP as part of the html screenshot. So just, provided the comment based on the screenshot.